Issue Using Regex Pattern in HTML Pattern Attribute
Issue Using Regex Pattern in HTML Pattern Attribute
I'm encountering an issue where a regex pattern that works correctly with the .test() method in JavaScript is not functioning as expected when used within an HTML pattern attribute. Here's the regex pattern:
/^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\))(?:[-\s()]*(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\)))*$/

When I try to use this pattern in the HTML pattern attribute, like so:
<input type="text" pattern="^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\))(?:[-\s()]*(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\)))*$">

I encounter the error:
Pattern attribute value /^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\))(?:[-\s()]*(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\)))*$/ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\))(?:[-\s()]*(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\)))*$//v: Invalid character in character class

Here are some inputs along with the expected results:
Input                               | Expected Result
---------------------------------------------------------
Guy Ben                             | true
Guy (a)                             | true
Guy (A)                             | true
Guy (A) B                           | true
John                                | true
John Smith                          | true
john                                | false
123                                 | false
!@#$%^&*()                          | false
John (123)                          | false
John Doe (a)                        | true
John-Doe                            | true
John-Doe-Smith                      | true
John-Doe-Smith (AB)                 | true
John (AB) Doe-Smith                 | true
John-Doe (AB) Smith                 | true
John (AB) Doe-Smith (C)             | true
John-Doe (AB) (C) Smith             | true
John-Doe (ABc) (C) Smith            | true
John (AB) Doe-Smith (C) (D)         | true
John (AB) Doe-Smith (C) (d)         | true
John (ABc) Doe-Smith                | true
John Doe-Smith (ab)                 | true
John-Doe (ABc) (D)                  | true
John (AB) (C) Doe-Smith             | true
John-Doe (AB) (c) Smith             | true
John (AB) (C) (D) Doe-Smith         | true
John-Doe (AB) (C) (d) Smith         | true
John-Doe (ABc) (D) (e) Smith        | true
John (ABc) (D) (E) Doe-Smith        | true
John-Doe (ABc) (D) (E) (F) Smith    | true

I'm unsure why this error occurs, especially since the regex works as expected in JavaScript. Can anyone provide insight into why this regex pattern is not accepted in the HTML pattern attribute?
Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

Little explain more with some test example @GuyBenDavid

@ArtBindu well since the regex cannot be parsed, it won't match anything in any test.

I need regex valid example to test it my end @Pointy

The problem seems to be with the character class [-\s()], it works with [\-\s\(\)]

The problem is caused by the fact that browsers have SILENTLY changed the pattern attribute to use the /v flag where those characters must be escaped within a character class.

Using regex.test() by addEventListener()

Inside the event listener, the current value of the input field is tested against the regular expression using regex.test(inputText.value).

If the input value matches the regular expression (i.e., it is valid), the condition inside the if statement is true. Otherwise, it is false.
const regex = /^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\))(?:[-\s()]*(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\)))*$/;

inputText.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (regex.test(inputText.value)) {
        // valid
    } else {
        // invalid
    }
});

Demo
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Input Validator</title>
    <style>
        .validity {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .validity.valid {
            background: url('https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/actions-ok-icon-26.png') no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        .validity.invalid {
            background: url('https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/x-png-22.png') no-repeat center center;
            background-size: contain;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Input Validator</h2>
    <form id="testForm">
        <label for="inputText">Enter a string:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="inputText" required>
        <span class="validity" id="validityIcon"></span>
    </form>

    <script>
        const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');
        const validityIcon = document.getElementById('validityIcon');
        const regex = /^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\))(?:[-\s()]*(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\((?:[A-Za-z]*?)\)))*$/;

        inputText.addEventListener('input', function() {
            if (regex.test(inputText.value)) {
                validityIcon.classList.remove('invalid');
                validityIcon.classList.add('valid');
            } else {
                validityIcon.classList.remove('valid');
                validityIcon.classList.add('invalid');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

regex visualization

Result


Awesome @BenchVue
